# Receiving spoofed packets

Tags: security, network-programming, scapy

I'm trying to send a fake echo response to a virtual machine that is trying to ping an IP address from another virtual machine. When I send ping from the victim VM, the terminal output of the victim VM says that there were no packets received but I can see that the fake response packets are received using wireshark on the victim VM. I tried turning off the firewall but nothing changed. Are there any other security measures that I'm not aware of? (Both VMs are Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: The sentence __"the packets are received through wireshark, it says 0 packets were received on the terminal"__ is a bit unclear to me. Please edit the question elaborate exactly what you do, where you see what packages and where not.

Comment: Do you fill the sequence of the ICMP properly ? The packet is most likely not identified as a valid answer